# Is it safe to manually define in your code constants/types availiable in future Linux kernel versions?

Tags: c++, linux, linux-kernel

Let's assume that there is an environment where SW building machines have very old Linux kernel version (e.g. `2.6.32`) and binaries which are built against this old kernel can be later used on systems with various newer kernel versions (`3.10` & `4.18`)

Let's also assume that I am working on a C++ library which provides some abstraction over Linux networking API. And as my SW is built agains an old kernel I have no access to some macro definitions/constants/types defined in modern kernels. But I still want to write code which uses features implemented in modern kenels (I can do runtime kernel version detection in my library).

One example of this can be the timestamping feature. `SOF_TIMESTAMPING_OPT_ID` socket option value is defined starting from kernel `3.17.0` and not available earlier. But I can define a constant with the same value as `SOF_TIMESTAMPING_OPT_ID` in my code and use it in `setsockopt` if it is detected at runtime that kernel version is >= `3.17.0`

Is it safe to define constants and types from future kernel versions in your code which is build against an old kernel? Do they (constant values/structure definitions) happen to change from one Linux kernel to another? Is such approach used in general when you need to support modern kernel features while building your SW against old kernels?

Comment: Why not? Also the glibc is not in sync to the kernel which it is running it.

Comment: Yes, just don't forget to guard it with `#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(3, 17, 0))`. And so on.

Comment: Regarding "why not": personally I do not expect that newer kernel can for example change value of existing constant as it sounds illogical, but I did not find any explicit statement that all existing constants in Linux kernel will never change their values.

Comment: It's an ABI, ABI is kept the way as it is now, i.e. no changes allowed, with very exceptional cases. At least this is a _status quo_ while Linus Torvalds is alive.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but why do you call it an ABI? From my perspective an ABI is e.g. a contract that setsockopt function is actually named setsockopt, it returns an integer  and takes 5 argument, each one of specific type. So after compilation all this is a binary interface. And the actual way how it behaves and how it treats different values passed in is more like an API.

Comment: The interface to userspace doesn't change, but the kernel internal structures change all the time